# css - hovering issue for sub navigation under the main navigation

Tags: css

I am trying to create a navigation like this. Basically, when the mouse hovers the "navigation1", the nested 'ul' block should show up as a submenu.

The nested 'ul' shows up as expected when the mouse hovers, but the issue is that the nested ul block (for submenu) shows up on top of the 'Navigation1', so it doesn't make the  whole 'Navigation1' link clickable. Only half of the text is clickable. I don't know why it shows up on top of it.

```
        <li id="sub_nav" style="vertical-align:top; margin-left: 110px; width:70px;"><a href="nav1.php">Navigation1</a>     
            <ul style="filter:alpha(opacity=100); opacity:1;  top:14px; padding: 0; margin-top:0px; margin-left: -67px; ">
                <li style="text-align: center; padding:0px; margin:0px; height:10px; background-color:#ffffff"><img src="imgs/nav_up_arrow.gif"/></li>
                <li style="height:15px;"><img src="imgs/i.gif" width="1" height="1"></li>
                <li style="margin-right:0px"><a href="sub1.php?id=1">Sub1</a></li>
                <li><a href="sub2.php?id=2">Sub2</a></li>
                <li><a href="sub3.php?id=3">Sub3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () { 

     $('ul#nav li#sub_nav').hover(
     function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(100);

     }, 
     function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);            
     }
   );
});
</script>

    #nav {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none;
}   

    /* make the LI display inline */
    /* it's position relative so that position absolute */
    /* can be used in submenu */
    #nav li {
        float:left; 
        display:block; 
        width:90px; 
        background:#fff; 
        position:relative;
        top: 87px;
        margin:0 1px;
    }

    /* this is the parent menu */
    #nav li a {
        display:block; 
        padding:8px 0px 0 0px; 
        font-weight:400;  
        height:23px;
        color: #6e6d6d;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-decoration:none; 
        text-align:center; 
    }


    /* submenu, it's hidden by default */
    #sub_nav ul {
        position:absolute; 
        left:0; 
        display:none;  
        margin:0 0 0 0; 
        padding:0; 
        list-style:none;
    }

    #sub_nav ul li {
        width:200px; 
        float:left; 
        top: 20px;
        border-top:0px #fff;
        margin-bottom: -9px;
        background-color:#000000;
    }

    /* display block will make the link fill the whole area of LI */
    #sub_nav ul a {
        color:#ccc;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 25px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    #sub_nav ul a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
```

I tried 'z-index:999' for the navigation1 and z-index:500 for the nested 'ul', but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'd appreciated if anybody has any idea.

Comment: it seems to work in your example, probably because your styles are missing. Can you provide a fiddle demonstrating your problem? I started one here, just add your styles or whatever it needs more http://jsfiddle.net/wcvWx/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you only have to style this way: 
1. li#subnav with position:relaitve; 
2. the nested ul with position absolute; and top as the same height as li#subnav.
This way the navigation1 link is going to be fully clickable.